# 2 websites wordpess and html on one domain

Tags: html, css, wordpress, dns, hosting

I have a website that is made on wordpress, and it is on the main domain for example test.com. From this wordpress application I need only production part and it will be on the subdomain product.test.com, and the main website will be on html and css. So the question is, can I do like that? And can this wordpress and html websites stay on different hostings?

And should I just change the wordpress application to product.test.com and then put the main html, css website on the main domain?

Comment: I dont think you can easily point a subdomain to a different IP,  or you will have to complicate things to much with reversd proxies or iframes. But on one hosting it is doable.

Comment: Depending on your hosting service, it's actually quite possible to point subdomains to different IPs.  I had my main domain on Adobe Portfolio, a shop.mydomain.com powered by Wordpress, and a links.mydomain.com powered by Github Pages.  It was a bit tricky to set up and make sure it all worked correctly, but 100% doable.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is doable
Just when you go to manage domain > setup dns > change nameservers here
Here you can put your customized DNS or A records etc whenever will be required
It may vary hosting to hosting but the core part will remains same